# Navigate css to element in div element

Tags: html, css

I need to navigate my css to an element, which is an element(div). Like this:

```
.element element {
  color: rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

How to do that? Info: `element > .element` didn't work, and `.element element` also didn't work.
I am trying to get the `toolbar` element. (here is the element in html):

```
<div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="toolbar">

    </div>
  </div>
```

And I need to get the toolbar element in main, because there are more toolbars in other divs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate my css?" Please provide some code.

Comment: @APAD1 Edited! :)

Comment: `element` is not necessarily a valid CSS selector, please provide the HTML as well so we can see which element you are trying to target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is used to select elements with a specific class, and `#` is used to select elements with a specific id. In your case to select the `.toolbar` nested within `#main` you would need:

```css
#main .toolbar {
  color: rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

Comment: If an ID is given, you should always use the ID in CSS. Your written rule may apply to other elements where a class "main" is given. Since the ID is UNIQUE, using the ID in a CSS-rule is more deterministic and "save" :)

Comment: @spyro good catch, I read the question too quickly and missed the id!

Comment: np :) Also, just for future readers, you may want to specify the path as accurate as possible to avoid unintended overlapping rules. So the 100% way to go for in this example would be by the selector `#main div.toolbar` :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML, your CSS should look like this:

```
.toolbar {
  color:rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

But since you have other elements with the class `toolbar`, you can use [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) so that only the element with class `toolbar` within the element with the id `main` will use those styles:

```css
#main .toolbar {
  color:rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main">
  <div class="toolbar">
    This is some text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 100%-correct way would be to go for the ID "main" and then select the DIV with the class, like: "#main div.toolbar" since this is even more accurate. If he now creates a span or href with the same class "toolbar" somewhere within the "#main", the rule still only applies to the div :)

Comment: True, but if you're assigning the same class to multiple different types of elements within the same parent element, I think you have bigger issues at hand ;)

Comment: Could be, yes, but there may be situations where this would be somewhat "ok". I would always try to define the selector as detailed as possible, so you don't get in trouble later ^^

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple:

```
#main div.toolbar {
color: red;
}
```

This targets the DIV with the class TOOLBAR within an element with the id MAIN :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little too abstract, but based on the code you added I think you're trying to target the div "toolbar", which can be done with any of the following (subjectively in the order of best-to-worst):

1. `#main .toolbar { ... }`
2. `.main .toolbar { ... }`
3. `#main div { ... }`
4. `.main div { ... }`

Comment: Always try to define the css selector as detailed as possible. In this case `#main div.toolbar` is the detailed definition one can give and this should be used. But you are right that there are many ways he can select this, which is the "best" at some point depends on his future html-structure :)

Comment: Indeed. I included those options because of how he asked the question.

Comment: Though I some methodology I read preferred `.toolbar` over `div.toolbar` because the 'div' part isn't semantic and doesn't help you understand the code. But if one was to consistently include the dom element in the selector, then why not `div#main div.toolbar`? 

So now I stick just to `#main .toolbar` in these cases. *shrug*

Comment: The reason why `div#main div.toolbar` won't make sense is that an ID is unique ;) So regardless of the DOM element, there will always be only one single element with the ID `main`, so you don't need DOM there. But in more complex code you for example do have a `<div class="toolbar">` and lateron you use a link that should be displayed properly like a toolbar and so you class it "toolbar" too. `Classes` are MADE fpr beeing used many many times with the same name. That's why you should narrow class-selectors down as much as possible :)

Comment: True, true. Though I still don't find myself doing `div.toolbar` because I don't often share class names with different types of DOM elements ... though for those who do it would certainly be helpful to list selectors that way. Or if you're inheriting something big.
In any case, this should be ample fodder for the OP to consider :)

Answer (score 0):

you can select in many ways, but if you want to navigate from one to another you should use on CSS (to access the toolbar)

```
.main div {
  color: rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

or you can simply use the css class selector to select the element directly

```
.toolbar {
    color: rgba(6, 132, 134, 255);
}
```

but this will not display anything, in order to see any content, you have to use the height property, or insert some content

Comment: Always try to define the css selector as detailed as possible. In this case `#main div.toolbar` is the detailed definition one can give and this should be used :)